# How to draw lines in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have to write a function drawLines that creates a view of defined lines. The first parameter is a tuple (columns, rows) defining the size of the resulting view. Left top corner has a coordinate (0,0). The second argument is a list of lines.

There is function for print:

```
pt :: Result -> IO ()
pt x = putStr (concat (map (++"\n") x))
```

Function:

```
drawLines :: (Int,Int) -> [Line] -> Result
```

Data types representing a point and a line:

```
data Point = Point Int Int
data Line = Line Point Point
```

There is IO example:

```
Prelude>pt(drawLines (31,15) [Line (Point x y) (Point 15 7)|(x,y)<-concat [[(x,y)|y<-[0,7,14]]|x<-[0,15,30]]])

 ##.............#.............##
 ..##...........#...........##..
 ....##.........#.........##....
 .....###.......#.......###.....
 ........##.....#.....##........
 ..........###..#..###..........
 .............#####.............
 ###############################
 .............#####.............
 ..........###..#..###..........
 ........##.....#.....##........
 .....###.......#.......###.....
 ....##.........#.........##....
 ..##...........#...........##..
 ##.............#.............##
```

Please help me. I tried something, but it doesn't work. Can someone explain to me how it works.
I tried this:

```
type Result = [String]
pt :: Result -> IO () 
pt x = putStr (concat (map (++"\n") x)) 
drawLines :: (Int,Int) -> [(Int,Int)] -> Result
drawLines (0,0) (x:xs) = [] drawLines (a,b) [] = [] 
drawLines (a,b) (x:xs) =[ [if a == fst x && b == snd x then 'x' else '.' | b 
<- [1..b]]| a <- [1..a]] ++ drawLines (a,b) xs
```

I'm a beginner in Haskell language.

Any advice will be good for me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called *"rasterization"*. There is a simple trick by which libraries such as [`diagrams`](https://archives.haskell.org/projects.haskell.org/diagrams/) rasterize their vector images, and I will let you in on it. Then you will have easy time writing the code.

The trick is this:

1. Define a function that determines if a point with given coordinates should be painted black or white.
2. Map this function all over the grid.

For example, suppose you have a line `Line (Point 1 2) (Point 3 4)`. You must be able to answer the question: should `Point 2 3` be black? Does the given line pass close enough to the given point for it to be painted black?

```
shouldIPaint :: Point -> Line -> Colour
```

Now, if you have 2 lines, and either one is close enough, you paint, and so on for any number of lines.

```
overlay :: [Colour] -> Colour

shouldIPaintMany :: Point -> [Line] -> Colour
shouldIPaintMany point = overlay . fmap (shouldIPaint point)
```

Seeing how a view is a collection of points, you need to determine the value of this function for each point. To this end, you may first create a view where every point holds its coordinates as values, then convert the coordinates to colour.

```
initialView :: Point -> View Point

solution :: Point -> [Line] -> View Colour
solution point lines = fmap (flip shouldIPaintMany lines) (initialView point)
```

Done! And the beauty here is that it is straightforward to extend this solution to paint in 3 dimensional space, or to paint circles as well as lines, and so on.

---

I do not really expect you to be able to fill in the missing parts all by yourself. You may have any number of questions by now, but these will be specific, sharp questions. Some of them will be about Mathematics, others will be about Haskell. If you want to be successful, you should write down these sharp questions, then try to answer them, and if you cannot, then ask them here on Stack Overflow or, maybe, at [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com). You can start by writing me a comment below this answer, and I will tell you if you are on the right track. It is also a possibility that you will not understand the solution I offered at first, but you really need to persist about it, and ask me if something does not make sense despite your best effort.